# unable to remove a file - terminal is splitting file name into two

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, ubuntu-18.04

Hie,

I know that the question might seems to basic or silly.

i have a file which is named

> 20190716000001_add_update_customer_review_ permission.sql

when I am trying to remove the file by the command rm

> rm ./20190716000001_add_update_customer_review_ permission.sql

I am receiving following output

```
rm ./20190716000001_add_update_customer_review_ permission.sql
rm: cannot remove './20190716000001_add_update_customer_review_': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'permission.sql': No such file or directory
```

the problem is that linux is splitting name into two. I don't have any idea why this is happening

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208140/deleting-files-with-spaces-in-their-names. While questions about writting commands for the shell are somehow related with programming, Stack Overflow is not a good place for them. See that question on meta for more info: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275757/when-is-it-ok-to-ask-shell-scripting-questions-on-so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a space between `review_` and `permission.sql`.

In order to `rm` the file you need to either add `\` before the space:

`rm ./20190716000001_add_update_customer_review_\ permission.sql`

or wrap the name with single quotes:

`rm './20190716000001_add_update_customer_review_ permission.sql'`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the name contains a space, run

```
rm ./'20190716000001_add_update_customer_review_ permission.sql'
```

to avoid word splitting.

Comment: thank you. In order to encourage new contributors I marking https://stackoverflow.com/a/57520397/9416473 as the answer.